# Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x11f10ac10 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED) SIGABRT ABORT 0x00000001b5efe84c

Tags: ios, swift, realm, operation

I'm getting a crash, reported in Crashlytics, and I have no idea how to reproduce the error, It happens randomly so it's hard to debug it with Xcode. Any ideas?

```
Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x11f10ac10 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1b5efe84c __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d211a9e8 pthread_kill + 212
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1934bd8f4 abort + 100
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x199b73030 _malloc_put + 554
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x199b732a4 malloc_zone_error + 100
5  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x199b732e0 nanov2_allocate_from_block$VARIANT$mp.cold.1 + 36
6  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x199b58498 nanov2_find_block_and_allocate$VARIANT$mp + 510
7  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x199b57710 nanov2_allocate$VARIANT$mp + 124
8  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x199b57644 nanov2_malloc$VARIANT$mp + 60
9  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x199b689ac _malloc_zone_malloc + 144
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18a6b7c14 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 264
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18a756fdc __CFSetApplyFunction_block_invoke + 24
12 CoreFoundation                 0x18a7f86f0 CFBasicHashApply + 136
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18a756f9c CFSetApplyFunction + 192
14 CoreFoundation                 0x18a747e50 CFRunLoopCopyAllModes + 136
15 CoreFoundation                 0x18a74c4ec __CFRunLoopSourceRemoveFromRunLoop + 64
16 CoreFoundation                 0x18a6ebab4 __CFBagApplyFunction_block_invoke + 48
17 CoreFoundation                 0x18a7f86f0 CFBasicHashApply + 136
18 CoreFoundation                 0x18a6eba5c CFBagApplyFunction + 84
19 CoreFoundation                 0x18a74c450 CFRunLoopSourceInvalidate + 208
20 Realm                          0x102993634 realm::util::EventLoopSignal<realm::_impl::WeakRealmNotifier::Callback>::~EventLoopSignal() + 24
21 Realm                          0x102888c70 realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator::unregister_realm(realm::Realm*) + 388
22 Realm                          0x10295a858 realm::Realm::~Realm() + 40
23 Realm                          0x10284c210 std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::_impl::CollectionNotifier>::~shared_ptr() + 64
24 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19eb37ae0 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 112
25 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19eb4d8a4 objc_destructInstance + 88
26 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19eb546ec _objc_rootDealloc + 52
27 Realm                          0x10292bcac -[RLMRealm dealloc] + 92
28 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19eb57574 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 200
29 libobjc.A.dylib                0x19eb57450 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 208
30 libswiftObjectiveC.dylib       0x1aea1bf4c autoreleasepool<A>(invoking:) + 68
31 Foresight                      0x100eaad74 specialized BloodPressureDataManager.getUnSyncedReadings(getHistoricData:fromAppleHealth:) + 441 (BloodPressure.swift:441)
32 Foresight                      0x100fccd14 specialized CloudDataManager.syncAllVitalData(withType:syncHistoricalData:fromAppleHealth:_:) + 408 (VitalDataManager.swift:408)
33 Foresight                      0x100dba408 SyncAllVitalOperation.main() + 4310885384 (<compiler-generated>:4310885384)
34 Foresight                      0x100dba560 @objc SyncAllVitalOperation.main() + 4310885728 (<compiler-generated>:4310885728)
35 Foresight                      0x101340af4 @objc SynchronizationOperation.start() + 4316678900 (<compiler-generated>:4316678900)
36 Foundation                     0x18ba84f98 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 20
37 Foundation                     0x18ba84a64 __NSOQSchedule_f + 180
38 libdispatch.dylib              0x18a3b775c _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 104
39 libdispatch.dylib              0x18a408280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
40 libdispatch.dylib              0x18a3ad390 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 412
41 libdispatch.dylib              0x18a3acad4 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 596
42 libdispatch.dylib              0x18a3b9f3c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
43 libdispatch.dylib              0x18a3ba704 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 124
44 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d211b568 _pthread_wqthread + 212
45 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d211e874 start_wqthread + 8
```

[image]

Please help me how to reproduce and debug this type of crash and What i need to check in my code related to crash.

Comment: Code from `BloodPressureDataManager.getUnSyncedReadings(getHistoricData:fromAppleHealth:)`, `CloudDataManager.syncAllVitalData(withType:syncHistoricalData:fromAppleHealth:_:)`, and maybe you NSOperation `SyncAllVitalOperation` might help.

Comment: The crash log indicates that the heap is corrupt. It's the result of using freed memory, writing outside of array boundaries etc. The bug corrupts the memory but is not detect until later. So the crash log does not point to the location of the bug. Use Xcode features such as Address Sanitizer, Malloc Scrible, Malloc Guard etc. to locate memory issues in your app.

Comment: Additional to Codos comment, to me it looks as a multi-threading problem. You should check if all accesses are thread safe. Maybe encapsulate those accesses into a separate GCD queue. In your case, an array seems to be corrupted, but this might just be a coincidence.

Comment: @Codo Thanks to reply, I have tried with these Xcode tools which you mentioned but i did not get anything.

Comment: The tools can only spot the problem if the bug is executed. So test all possible scenarios, test different devices, test in poor and changing network conditions, test, test, test until you discover the bug. I don't see any other option.